# comparing two objects of same type return false in c#

Tags: c#, list

I have Two lists of Class **lin**

```
public class lin
        {
            public string DB_Name;
            public string Object_Name;
        }
List<lin> lines1 = new List<lin>();
List<lin> lines2 = new List<lin>();
```

I have assign some values to these two lists 
below is the output of list **lines1** at index 5 from Immediate window which contains `DB_Name = "aesdb_s1"` and `Object_Name = "tblAsiAliasItem"`

```
 lines1[5] 
        DB_Name: "aesdb_s1"
        Object_Name: "tblAsiAliasItem"
```

also the **lines2** at index 0 (zeero) have the same values

```
lines2[0]
    DB_Name: "aesdb_s1"
    Object_Name: "tblAsiAliasItem"
```

but when i compare these two objects or try to get index of value it returns false

```
lines1.IndexOf(lines2[0])
-1

lines1.Contains(lines2[0]);
false

lines1[5]==lines2[0]
false
```

Above is the output of immediate window from visual studio

Comment: how did you try to compare those lists ? please post that code also

Comment: How are you adding the objects to the list?

Comment: I already have posted the output of Immidiate window you can see in my question

Comment: It will not copmpare them via `==`. you should override `equals`

Comment: By default, classes offer reference-based equality. I'm assuming that your objects are *semantically equivalent*, but are different object instances. That isn't enough: they will report as different.

Comment: @RoyiNamir and `GetHashCode()`; `Equals` and `GetHashCode` should always be compatible with each-other

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes. Just pointed out what is the reason :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing the objects by reference.  Not by value...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183752.aspx

If you want to compare them, you need to [override the `Equals()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx) method in your `lin` class to specifically compare each of the properties.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `lin` that would work like you expect:

```
public class Lin : IEquatable<Lin>
{
    public string DbName {get;set;}
    public string ObjectName {get;set;}

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        return Equals(obj as Lin);
    }
    public bool Equals(Lin other) {
        return other != null
           && this.DbName == other.DbName
           && this.ObjectName == other.ObjectName;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        int x = DbName == null ? 0 : DbName.GetHashCode();
        int y = ObjectName == null ? 0 : ObjectName.GetHashCode();
        return (-1423 * x) ^ y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this assumes `DbName` and `ObjectName` are case-sensitive.

Comment: @Brian yes; and that is a pretty decent assumption; case insensitivity should be explicit...

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the whole solution even for `==` :

```
 public class lin : IEquatable<lin>
        {
            public string DB_Name;
            public string Object_Name;

            public bool Equals(lin other)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
                if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
                return string.Equals(DB_Name, other.DB_Name) && string.Equals(Object_Name, other.Object_Name);
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
                if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
                if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
                return Equals((lin) obj);
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                unchecked { return ((DB_Name != null ? DB_Name.GetHashCode() : 0)*397) ^ (Object_Name != null ? Object_Name.GetHashCode() : 0); }
            }

            public static bool operator ==(lin left, lin right)
            {
                return Equals(left, right);
            }

            public static bool operator !=(lin left, lin right)
            {
                return !Equals(left, right);
            }
        }
```